# R: Topology Exception Error

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I'm trying to do the `gDifference` between two polygons, but I was getting an error:

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_not_poly, "rgeos_intersection") : TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point.
```

So I did this:

```
polygone1 <- gBuffer(polygone1, byid=TRUE, width=0)
polygone2 <- gBuffer(polygone2, byid=TRUE, width=0)
res <- gDifference(polygone1, polygone2)
```

But now I'm getting another error:

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, "rgeos_difference") : 
  TopologyException: EdgeRing::computePoints: found null Directed Edge
```

Is there a way to fix this? Doing the same exact thing with Erase function in ArcGIS works perfectly fine.

Comment: have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419149/join-geospatial-boundaries-dissolve-polygons) answer and read the references therein?

Comment: have you checked that all your features are valid using `gIsValid`? Have you tried removing, or correcting invalid ones?

Comment: yes, I did. all the features are valid

Comment: could you make your polygon data available, so we can take a look?